# Structure inheritance in C

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to inherit structure with another in standard C or C++?

Comment: "Is a car or red a color?" - Yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C does not support inheritance.

C++ does support inheritance.

Comment: @James, can you kindly send me the reference??

Comment: @Arman:  Sure.  Stack Overflow has [a list of good beginner C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and [a list of good beginner C books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Any of those beginner books would contain this information.

Comment: @Arman - uhmmm.... you should google for ANSI C Standard + wg14...your comment's undertones sounds like as if you don't believe his answer and that you're sceptical....

Comment: @tommieb75, I have accepted James answer, I am just asking for the reference for my own knowledge.

Comment: @tommieb75, I usually ask the question on SO before google, because I got the right direction from other's experience.

Comment: @Arman, here is another reference: http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf

Comment: @Arman: well I am so sorry to see SO being downgraded to asking questions that can easily be found out elsewhere or the fact that - it never dawned on you to google using the keywords standard c, which was the basis of this question, there's far too many low quality questions being asked by contributors like yourself who are expressing themselves lazily.... and asking others to do the work for them...

Comment: @Arman C _does not and never will_ support inheritance. That is why the force was used and we have C++. You can `ad hoc` similar behaviour using function pointers, type safe callbacks and an overall egregious abuse of the language given the fact that C++ exists, but _why?_ You can grab enough from CCAN (hint, typesafe CB's, antithread, talloc and more) to pull this off in C, but again, WHY?

Answer (score 13):

You can embed a structure inside another to simulate inheritance in C:

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
} base;

void basefunc(base *b);

typedef struct {
    base b;
    char c;
} extended;

extended e;
/* Initialise extended here */
basefunc(&e.b);      /* Use the type checker */
basefunc((base*)&e); /* Just make sure you know what you're doing */
```

Comment: Yep. Though it leaves you with the awkward `e.b.i` syntax for accessing the "base" members. But that's just another reason to wrap all this up as a opaque type...

Comment: Or, since a pointer to a struct is guaranteed to also point to its first member, you can cast it - `basefunc ( ( base*) e )`

Comment: @Pete Kirkham, thanks, I've added that to my answer with a warning.

Comment: You can have [anonymous structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972003/how-to-use-anonymous-structs-unions-in-c) which avoid the `e.b.i` syntax.

Comment: That's just as close as you can get. Still: e.g. the access to a member of struct base involves the necessarity of casting, there is no function /method overloading, you won't have methods, so you have to pass in a pointer to your struct every time you want to operate on the object represented by it. There are books on object - orientated programming with ANSI - C but they pretty much related to implementing a framework to simulate the features of C++ and can't resolve the described issues.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference between `struct` and `class` is default visibility of members and default inheritance mode. `struct D : B { ...` is equivalent to `class D : public B { public: ...`.