# c++ Declaration Rect structure with union

Tags: c++

I want to declare Rect structure:

```
struct{
   float x,y;
   float width,height;
}Rect;
```

And union variables x,y to 'pos' and width,height to 'size' Vector2f structure:

```
struct{
   float x,y;
}Vector2f;
```

How can i do it with union?

```
Rect rect; 
//rec.x; rec.y; rect.pos; rect.pos.x; rect.pos.y; 
//rect.width; rect.height; rect.size; rect.size.x; rect.size.y;
```

Comment: what? why do you want to use union?

Comment: Don't think Union does what *you* think it does : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4527955/399317 (also shows an alternative solution with accessor functions rather than a union)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for **anonymous unions**. The syntax is:

```
struct Rect {

   union {
       Vector2f pos;
       struct {
           float x,y;
       };
   };
   union {
       Vector2f size;
       struct {
           float width, height;
       };
   };

};
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/JgqABu

*(I don't recommend doing that though; I'd just [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and use the vectors.)*

Answer (score 2):

You’ve got the syntax wrong: the name of the struct comes before the body, not after it:

```
struct Rect {
   float x, y;
   float width, height;
};
```

There, now you’re good to go.

But note that “union” means something completely different in C++. A `union` is a data structure which, like a `struct`, groups objects. But while every instance of a `struct` can hold multiple values simultaneously, an instance of a `union` can only hold a *single* value at a time. They have their uses, but those are pretty rare and there are usually better (and type safe) ways of accomplishing the same.