# How to use c union nested in struct with no name

Tags: c++, c, struct, unions, anonymous

I'm working on the so called Hotspot open source project, and looking at the implementation I found a nasty nested union in struct looking like that:

```
typedef struct RC_model_t_st
{
    union
    {
        struct block_model_t_st *block;
        struct grid_model_t_st *grid;
    };
    /* block model or grid model    */
    int type;
    thermal_config_t *config;
}RC_model_t;
```

As far as I'm aware in C/C++ that union is unaccesible. So how someone can make use of union declared in such manner and for what purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972003/how-to-use-anonymous-structs-unions-in-c

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is an *anonymous union.* In C++, as per [class.union], paragraph 5:

> For the purpose of name lookup, after the anonymous union definition,
>   the members of the anonymous union are considered to have been defined
>   in the scope in which the anonymous union is declared

This means you can access its members as if they were members of `RC_model_t_st`.

Comment: Ok. Then if I can access them as members of the structure, I don't understand why would someone put them in anonymous union?

Comment: @zwx Because it's still a union - they occupy the same storage space.

Comment: With every variable, you allocate some memory space of n bytes. Now the variables type defines only, how much space and how the content of this space is to be interpreted. With a union, the variable uses the space of the biggest type, the interpretation depends on the member you access

Answer (score 11):

Without being sure and without having tried:

The union itself is not accessible, but it's members are.

Therefore you should be able to do refer to `obj.block` and `obj.grid`

Comment: You mean that obj is RC_model_t?

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on the answer provided by Angew quoting the standard concerning anonymous unions and structs, I thought to provide an sample of C source code with the output generated by that sample showing how values are allocated within a `struct` and a `union` composed of `struct` and `union` components.

The standard quoted by Angew is:

> For the purpose of name lookup, after the anonymous union definition,
>   the members of the anonymous union are considered to have been defined
>   in the scope in which the anonymous union is declared.

The source code of a `struct` composed of named and anonymous structs and unions looks like the following. This is using Visual Studio 2005 and the `#pragma (pack, 1)` is used to align everything on a `char` boundary in order for there to be no memory holes. There is also a simple C Preprocessor macro defined to make the output more legible and easier to code.

```
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;

// use of Microsoft Visual Studio pragma to force char alignment for the struct.
#pragma pack(push, 1)
const struct {
    union {
        const UCHAR myArray[];  // this array shares memory with struct following
        struct {
            const UCHAR iOne;
            const UCHAR iTwo;
            const UCHAR iThree;
        };  // anonymous struct accessed by specifying Things.
    };      // anonymous union accessed by specifying Things.
//  const UCHAR myArray[];   // will cause error - "error C2020: 'myArray' : 'struct' member redefinition"
    union {
        const UCHAR myArray[];  // this array shares memory with struct following
        struct {
            const UCHAR iOne;
            const UCHAR iTwo;
            const UCHAR iThree;
        } s;    // named struct accessed by specifying Things.u.s
    } u;        // named union accessed by specifying Things.u
} Things = {1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 22, 23, 24, 25};
#pragma pack(pop)

// a little helper macro to make the output easier to code.
#define PRINTF_VAL(x) printf ("%s %d \n", #x, x)

int itSelf (UCHAR iMask)
{
    int iMatch = -1;

    int jj = 0;
    jj = Things.myArray[0]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.myArray[0]);
    jj = Things.myArray[1]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.myArray[1]);
    jj = Things.myArray[2]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.myArray[2]);
    jj = Things.myArray[3]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.myArray[3]);
    jj = Things.myArray[4]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.myArray[4]);
    jj = Things.iOne; PRINTF_VAL(Things.iOne);
    jj = Things.iTwo; PRINTF_VAL(Things.iTwo);
    jj = Things.iThree; PRINTF_VAL(Things.iThree);

    jj = Things.u.myArray[0]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.myArray[0]);
    jj = Things.u.myArray[1]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.myArray[1]);
    jj = Things.u.myArray[2]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.myArray[2]);
    jj = Things.u.myArray[3]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.myArray[3]);
    jj = Things.u.myArray[4]; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.myArray[4]);
    jj = Things.u.s.iOne; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.s.iOne);
    jj = Things.u.s.iTwo; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.s.iTwo);
    jj = Things.u.s.iThree; PRINTF_VAL(Things.u.s.iThree);

    return iMatch + 1;
}
```

The output generated by this function looks like:

```
Things.myArray[0] 1
Things.myArray[1] 2
Things.myArray[2] 4
Things.myArray[3] 8
Things.myArray[4] 9
Things.iOne 1
Things.iTwo 2
Things.iThree 4
Things.u.myArray[0] 8
Things.u.myArray[1] 9
Things.u.myArray[2] 10
Things.u.myArray[3] 22
Things.u.myArray[4] 23
Things.u.s.iOne 8
Things.u.s.iTwo 9
Things.u.s.iThree 10
```

The output shows the overlap between the various components of the main `struct`, `Things` caused by the use of unions. You can also see how the components of the anonymous `struct` and `union` are referenced versus those components of the named `struct` and `union`.

Also just for fun I tried adding an array definition of `const UCHAR myArray[];` after the anonymous `union` containing `const UCHAR myArray[];` to see what would happen. The compiler complained with an error of `error C2020: 'myArray' : 'struct' member redefinition`. The addition is commented out in the `struct` definition of `Things` above. However since the second use of `const UCHAR myArray[];` is in a named `union` the compile works because second use is accessed by specifying the name of the union.

Answer (score 8):

This code here (https://gist.github.com/klange/4042963) shows how to access anonymous unions inside struct. You just access the members of nested union as if they are members of the struct.

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        char * company;
        char * school;
        char * project;
    };
    union {
        char * location;
        char * url;
    };
    union {
        char * title;
        char * program;
    };

    time_t started;
    time_t left;

    char * description[];
} thing_t;

typedef thing_t job_t;

job_t yelp = {
    .company  = "Yelp, Inc.",
    .location = "San Francisco, CA",
    .title    = "Software Engineer, i18n",
    .started  = 1339977600,
    .left     = CURRENT,
    .description = {
        "Developed several internal tools and libraries",
        "Provided critical input and design work for Yelp's launch in Japan",
        NULL
    }
};
```

Comment: Code shown would not compile due to the non-static declaration of `description`, e.g. `"non-static initialization of a flexible array member"`. You either provide a size (making it not a FAM) or you must allocate for the struct *plus* storage for the number of pointers you will use.

Answer (score 4):

Names declared in an anonymous union are used directly, like nonmember variables.
A good reason to do this is to save memory.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   union {
      double first;
      double second;
   };

   first = 10.001;
   second = 3.141592;
   std::cout << first << " " << second << std::endl;

   first = 10.002;
   std::cout << first << " " << second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: if you put out the results of your code, that's gonna be more helpful. (though we can run it by ourself)

Answer (score -2):

first of all i want to say that **A union, is a collection of variables of different types, just like a structure. However, with unions, you can only store information in one field at any one time.**

The unions are basically used for memory saving & **it's size is equal to the largest member of the union.**

**And for accessing the data fields of a union, use the dot operator(.) just as you would for a structure and explained by @Atmocreations. When a value is assigned to one member, the other member(s) get whipped out since they share the same memory.**

as an example where the unions may be useful is

```
union time    
        {
        long time_in_sec;
        double time_in_mili_sec;
        }mytime;
```

....
The union above could be used to either store the current time (in seconds) to hold time accurate to a second. Or it could be used to hold time accurate to a millisecond. Presumably there are times when you would want one or the other, but not both. This declaration should look familiar. It is the same as a struct definition, but with the keyword union instead of struct.

for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @akp: Pay attention. Alignment could break this depending on the architecture

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.