# make vector 3D derived from vector ND, need to retain field x y z

Tags: c++, inheritance, field, unions

I have a vector 3D class

```
class Vector3D{
    public: float x; float y; float z;
    //some functions, e.g. operator+ - * / 
    //some 3D-specific function
};
```

and a vector N-D class.

```
template<int constSize> class VecFloatFix{
    float database[constSize];
    //some functions, e.g. operator+ - * / 
};
```

I noticed that there is code-duplication between two classes, so I think I should make `Vector3D` derived from `VecFloatFix<3>` :-

```
class Vector3D : public VecFloatFix<3>{
    //some 3D-specific function
};
```

Everything seems to be good, except that there are a lot of user code access `Vector3D::x,y,z` directly.

Is it possible to make `Vector3D` derived from `VecFloatFix<3>` while not break user's code?

My best guess is around :-

```
template<int constSize> class VecFloatFix{
    union{
        float database[constSize];
        float x,y,z;  ?????  sound like a hack
    }
    //some functions, e.g. operator+ - * / 
};
```

**Edit:** Hardcoding `x,y,z` into `VecFloatFix` is unsustainable.
If I have a new class `Vector2D` that derived from `VecFloatFix<2>`, `Vector2D::z` will compile fine (dangerous).

Comment: If `database` in `VecFloatFix` is  `protected`, or `public`, you could do something like `float& x = database[0];` in `Vector3D` class.

Comment: There are various workarounds that might get you what you want, but it depends on what your client code is doing. Ultimately, I'd question the value of what you are trying to do. Just keep the two types separate and provide facilities for their interoperation (e.g. conversion between the two).

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius That is genius!  I don't know it is possible.

Comment: in your example x,y,z will be placed in one float (database[0]), so vec.x = 100.0 will make vec.y==100.0 too. You can make `struct {float x,y,z;};` to avoid this.

Comment: is it on purpose that `x`,`y`,`z` are public, while `database` is private?

Comment: @Joseph Thomson Thank.   It is a good idea.  My client read&write `x,y,z`, but never cache its address.

Comment: @tobi303  Yes, it is by-design.  `x y z` is public to shorten calling (math/physic notation), while `VecFloatFix` is kept as private for encapsulation (I also provide `operator[]` though).

Comment: @em2er  Thank, that is very useful.

Comment: AAlgirdasPreidžius This will most likely result in a lot of wasted space per object.

Comment: @n.m. I hate when you are always correct.  http://ideone.com/HhoDMo  (sizeof = 12 vs 40)  no.... you destroy my dream again

Comment: References typically take space (this is permitted though not mandated by the standard).

Comment: Seems like we might learn a lesson here: If you make fields public, it is hard to change the implementation later without affecting user code.

Comment: I don't know how many undefined behavior it will bring, but — is it possible to use `union Vector3D { VecFloatFix<3> _base; struct { float x, y, z; }; };`?

Comment: @Bo Persson  I am stubborn.  I still think the design is correct.  `solve(a.x,a.y,c.x,c.y)` is much cuter than  `solve(a.x(),a.y(),c.x(),c.y())`.    If I have no choice, I might use the notorious macro.  *bwa bwaaa...*

Comment: @kennytm It is an unsustainable hack.  Its only one disadvantage -  if I have `Vector2D` derived from `VecFloatFix<2>`, it is dangerous when user calls `Vector2D::z` (no compile error).

Comment: @javaLover Yes it is a hack, but I don't see how Vector2D is relevant. The union is defined for Vector3D only.

Comment: @kennytm sorry, I didn't read you comment carefully.  I will test it!

Comment: @kennytm  I tested, it doesn't solve.   http://ideone.com/xMPNHM   It can't recognize operator.

Comment: @javaLover: Looking at your username, shouldn't you consider `solve(a.getX(), a.getY(), c.getX(), c.getY());` cutest?

Comment: @Christian Hackl I am still struggling to adapt myself to fit in this c++ wonderland.  I think it is cool to have `Public Attributes : Real x`  from http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_vector3.html.   I usually don't do like this.  But for this specific class, the convenience is much more than the annoyance of my broken encapsulation.

Comment: @javaLover: I think your Java background makes you think too much in terms of types. A more suitable philosophy for C++ is based on the original STL ideas which have become so important in the standard library: separate container types from algorithms. Try to not squeeze `Vector3D` and `VecFloatFix<T>` into one class. Aim for generic operations which can operate with both types, *and* with the Ogre vector. Now that would fit into this C++ wonderland! :) Use type traits as helpers to achieve that goal.

Comment: @Christian Hackl  After staring for some time, I feel there is some great wisdom hiding in your posts (around "generic operations" and "type_traits").  Thank, I will follow the light your provided. XD

Answer (score 2):

This is by no ways guaranteed to work as it uses implementation-defined and possibly undefined behaviour. A *sensible* implementation will *probably* behave as expected though.

```
template<int constSize> 
class VecFloatFix{
public:
  union {
    float database[constSize];
    struct {
        int x, y, z;
    };
  };
};
```

This also leaves `database` public. Don't see a way around this, but no big deal since you provide `operator[]` anyway.

This assumes `constSize >= 3`. If you need smaller sizes, this is doable through a bit more hackery. All vectors will have `x` `y` and `z` members but only 3D and above will have them all usable. The 2D vector will have only `x` and `y` usable (any use of `z` is likely to result in an error) and the 1D vector will have just `x`. Note I refuse to take responsibility for any of the following.

```
template<int constSize>
class VecFloatFix{
    public:
        union {
            float database[constSize];
            struct {
                float x;
            };
            struct {
                spacer<constSize, 1> sp1;
                typename spacer<constSize, 1>::type y;
            };
            struct {
                spacer<constSize, 2> sp2;
                typename spacer<constSize, 2>::type z;
            };
        };
};
```

where `spacer` is defined this way:

```
template <int N, int M, bool enable>
struct filler;

template <int N, int M>
struct filler<N, M, true>
{
    float _f[M];
    typedef float type;
};

template <int N, int M>
struct filler<N, M, false>
{
    struct nothing {};
    typedef nothing type;
};

template <int N, int M>
struct spacer
{
    filler<N, M, (N>M)> _f;
    typedef typename filler<N, M, (N>M)>::type type;
};
```

Test drive:

```
VecFloatFix<4> vec4;
VecFloatFix<3> vec3;
VecFloatFix<2> vec2;
VecFloatFix<1> vec1;

`smoke test`
vec3.database[0] = 42;
vec2.database[1] = 99;
std::cout << vec3.x << std::endl;
std::cout << vec2.y << std::endl;

// make sure `y` aliases `database[1]`
std::cout << & vec2.y << std::endl;
std::cout << & vec2.database[1] << std::endl;

// make sure sizes are as expected
std::cout << sizeof(vec4) << " " << sizeof (vec3) << " " << sizeof(vec2) << " " << sizeof(vec1) << std::endl;
```

Comment: What is this hackery called?

Comment: No idea but it's nasty.

Comment: I know that you won't responsible for any damage toward anything.  ... I just want to tell that I can access `vec2.z` without compile error.  http://ideone.com/KAMNrm  I guess it is not your intention.

Comment: The version by @Tulon seems much simpler and cleaner so I probably should delete mine.

Comment: That's because I had a typo there, `typename spacer<constSize, 1>::type z;` should have `2`, not `1`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that only exposes `x`, `y`, `z` components for vectors of size 3. Obviously other sizes may also be specialized.

```
template<int constSize> struct VecFloatStorage
{
    float database[constSize];
};

template<> struct VecFloatStorage<3>
{
    union
    {
        float database[3];
        struct { float x, y, z; };
    };
};

template<int constSize> class VecFloatFix : public VecFloatStorage<constSize>
{
public:
    // Methods go here.
};
```

I don't know if the standard guarantees `struct { float x, y, z; }` to have the same memory layout as `float data[3]`, however in practice I am pretty certain that assumption holds.

The `GLM` library is using a similar trick, except they don't have an array member at all, instead providing an indexing operator that returns `(&this->x)[idx]`.

Comment: As n.m. stated, it is implementation-defined (i.e. unreliable).  I just found two link describes about "anonymous struct" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878 (better description) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13624760.  It is sad, because this solution is very beautiful.