# standard interface of iterator::operator* that return more than T& and std::pair

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

Iterator of each datastructure has different type of return value of `operator*()` e.g. :-

- Most array-like `DataStructure<T>` : return `T&`.
- `std::unordered_map<K,T>`   : return `std::pair<const K, T>&`.
- `const std::unordered_map<K,T>` : return `const std::pair<K, T>&`.

What should be the datatype if my `iterator::operator*()` want to return something more complex (`std::pair` is not enough)?

### Example

I have a custom 3D datastructure `Map3D<T>` that is like a map `(int,int,int)->T`.

To achieve the above requirement, I create a new class `Bundle3D<T>`.

```
template<class T>class Bundle3D {
    //getInternalIndex1D()
    //getCoordinate()
    //getValue()
};
```

The `Map3D<T>`'s `iterator::operator*` would have signature like :-

```
Bundle3D<T> iterator::operator*(){ ... }
```

Its usage is like :-

```
Map3D<float> map;
for(auto& ele:map){  //"ele" has some special type named "Bundle"
    int keyInternal1DIndex=ele.getInternalIndex1D();
    Vector3Int& key=ele.getCoordinate();
    float& value=ele.getValue();
}
```

It works good, but I think my code is not ***standardized***.
In other words, `Bundle3D<T>`, `getInternalIndex1D()`, `getCoordinate()` and `getValue()` is blindly named by me.

In real case, I have created a lot of custom data-structures that generate such strange iterator.

### Question

Is there any `std::`/standard type of return-value of `iterator::operator*()`, when `T&` and `std::pair` is not enough?

I have doubted about this for several months, but feel very reluctant to ask it.
If this question need improvement, please comment.

### **Edit**

(clarify the word ***standardized*** - this part is my subjective notion.)

I feel that all types of standard collection in most language, e.g. :-

- `java.util.Collection/ArrayList` in Java
- `std::unordered_map/vector` in C++

Iterators of all of them  have signatures of function `getValue()` or `operator*` that return either `T` or `StandardPair<index,T>` - no other types.

For many years, I am convinced that it is a rule or a strong convention/tradition that I really should obey.

There must be a reason.
However, I am not sure what it is, because I am probably very new to C++.

If I design my software to return something strange (e.g. `Bundle3D<T>` in the above example), I think I will get punished hard from the *unconventional* design.  (e.g. not have `.first` field)

Comment: Never feel reluctant to ask. Can you tell me what you mean by "standardized"? If you seek conformance with the standard library algorithms, the mere fact you implemented an iterator is already standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller  Thank for cheering me up.  :)   I have edited the question to clarify the word.

Comment: If your container behaves similarly to `std::map<std::tuple<int,int,int>,T>`, the iterators probably should look the same too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have right now is okay. I would just specify one thing that I think isn't very C++-ish and may in fact harm your standardization options in the future.

It's the getters. Obviously you have deep roots in Java, and the concept of public members is abhorred in Java programming, so much so that the concept of "beans" exists. I don't intend to knock on Java here, it's a nice language with its own nice idioms.

But this is C++, with it's own programming idioms. You obviously noticed the direct access to the contents of `std::pair`. It's like that for a reason. A pair is just two items packed together, that's the sum of its behavior. Getters would just ,well, get in the way. :)
There's no need for them, because we aren't dealing with an "abstraction" of two items bundled together, but instead we really do have a concrete, honest to god, bundle<sup>1</sup>.

Obviously we can have bundles of more than two items. That's why we have `std::tuple`. Now while it's true that all access to a tuple is through a non-member function called `get`, that's simply because there is no way to give names to members of an arbitrarily sized bundle. `get` still returns a reference to the element, so you retain direct access into the bundle.

This long winded exposition is important, because an upcoming C++1z feature, called ["Structured Bindings"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf), relies on the standard behavior of tuples and pairs, as well as how C++ programmers see aggregates. Under this feature, an iteration over a map, will look like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

std::map<char const*, int> foo()
{
    return {
        { "foo", 3 },
        { "bar", 7 },
        { "baz", 1 },
    };
}

int main() {

    for (auto [key, val] : foo()) {
        std:: cout << "( " << key << ", " << val << " )\n";
    }

   return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45cf5e32f167f0f0)</kbd>

And the same extends to any user defined bundle of data. Your own return value type in the post can be bound similarly, if the members are public:

```
struct Vector3Int {};

template<class T>
struct Bundle3D {
    int               internal_index_id;
    Vector3Int const &coord;
    T                &value;
};

int main() {
  Vector3Int vec;
  float val;
  Bundle3D<float> bundle{ 1, vec, val };

  auto[ idx_id, coord, value] = bundle;

  // coord = {}; // compile error since coord gets the cv qualifer

}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9012772476b8e18)</kbd>

So my suggestion is, leave the getters to your Java code, and use aggregates as bundles of data for C++.

---

<sup>1</sup> An aggregate, to be more formal.

Comment: Why access field directly is more OK in C++ than Java.  I am skimming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737409/are-get-and-set-functions-popular-with-c-programmers still get no idea.  .... I have bad experiences when expose public member e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885210/make-vector-3d-derived-from-vector-nd-need-to-retain-field-x-y-z.

Comment: @javaLover - Yup, typo (I have read over before posting, but selective blindness :) ). As for why we prefer direct access, well, it all comes to the realization that there's no encapsulation here really. We just want to return two items, why make it cumbersome? That's my opinion anyway.

Comment: @javaLover - Regarding your bad experience, I can only say it's a matter of judgment. Sometimes direct access is indeed bad, and for future proofing we shouldn't do that. But that depends on the responsibility of the object, if it harbors logic, and not just data.

For a simple aggregate, the responsibility is just a "hold these arbitrary values together in memory". So direct access suffices.

Comment: `coord` really should be a `const Vector3Int &`, because mutating keys will likely break the map

Comment: I will assume a possible situation : I plan that the `Bundle` store only `index1D` because most loop-range will just want to access the 1D index.   The `getCoordinate()` is rarely used, so it is allowed to use an expensive algorithm (e.g. convert 1D->3D).  If it become that way, I should leave it as a function, right?  i.e. it is really depends on what I am planning to do with it in the future. ?  .... I think bundle/function is the safest path.

Comment: @javaLover - Yup, leave it as function. You have an abstraction, and should not violate it. Even if your return value isn't fit for structured binding, the original loop in your post will always work. That's why I said to start with, that you have an okay setup :)

Comment: Thank for dedicating a lot of time to explain me in deep detail. XD

Comment: @javaLover - NP. It's an interesting topic to discuss. And I'm always happy to bend someone's ear about C++ philosophy :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your `Map3D` is a spacial co-ordinate to value container.

I would return a `std::pair<const Vector3Int, T>&`, and not bother with getInternalIndex1D as part of the return. That can be left as a function Vector3Int -> int.

Have a look at [UnorderedAssociativeContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnorderedAssociativeContainer) for the sorts of members that would be useful to define

e.g.

```
template <typename T>
class Map3D
{
    using key_type = Vector3Int;
    using mapped_type = T;
    using value_type = Bundle3D<T>; // Key, Value, Internal1DIndex
    using reference = Bundle3D<T> &;
    using pointer = Bundle3D<T> *;
    using hasher = /*Function object that calculates Internal1DIndex*/
    using key_equal = std::equal<Vector3Int>
    ... iterators, const_* definitions, etc
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is spacial co-ordinate to value container.   Converting "const Vector3Int" to int would cost a little bit, so I am reluctant to omit it.   By the way, it is a nice answer, thank.

Comment: I wouldn't expose Internal1DIndex to outside code, just use instances of `iterator` to denote internal position

Comment: Good point.   From my situation, there are other data-structures (e.g. named `Map3D2`) which works similar to `Map3D`.   The `internal1DIndex` enable me to call  `map3D2.setIndexInternalHack(internal1DIndex,key3D,value)` to get some performance boost.   I don't want to lose that advantage. Do you happen to know a way to retain it?

Comment: Yes, but in your solution, I can't access from `ele` inside `for(auto& ele:map){`.

Comment: Ok. There's nothing from stopping you from using a different `Map3D::value_type`. I've edited to include the internal index, which you might want to extend to include a `const Vector3Int & first = get<0>();` and `T & second = get<1>();` so as to look more like pair

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143870/discussion-between-caleth-and-javalover).